# How to run query on multiple values on single column in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, search, eloquent

I have used multi-select in laravel search.  I want to search for data on multiple values.
Here is my code

**getting an array from the request**

`$req->state`

Getting all the data from request

```
[
'DELHI','MAHARASHTRA','KARNATAKA',
]
```

```
$data = tbl_company::query()
                ->where(
                    "state",
                    [$req->state]
                )->paginate(100);
```

Comment: use `whereIn` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Comment: ```SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number``` GETTING THIS ERROR

Comment: not working sir

Answer (score 1):

I was passing an arary inside an array and istead of `where` i wrote `whereIn`

```
$data = tbl_company::where(
                    "state",
                    [$req->state] //passing array inside an array
                )->paginate(100);
```

**Answer**

```
$data = tbl_company::query()
                ->whereIn(
                    "state",
                    $req->state
                )->paginate(100);
```